# Post-Build Event, Copy command not correct?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, post-build-event

I am trying to do the following:

```
set strSolutionDir= "$(SolutionDir).."
 
SET SeaProjectPATH= %strSolutionDir%\$(ProjectName)\bin
SET SeaMainMenuPATH= %strSolutionDir%\seamainmenu\bin

    COPY /Y %SeaProjectPATH%\$(ProjectName).dll   %SeaMainMenuPATH%\$(ProjectName).dll
    COPY /Y %SeaProjectPATH%\$(ProjectName).pdb %SeaMainMenuPATH%\$(ProjectName).pdb

SET SeaProjectCrystalPATH= %strSolutionDir%\$(ProjectName)\CrystalFiles
SET SeaMainMenuCrystalPATH= %strSolutionDir%\seamainmenu\bin\CrystalFiles

attrib -r %SeaMainMenuCrystalPATH%\*.*

COPY /Y %SeaProjectCrystalPATH%\*.rpt   %SeaMainMenuCrystalPATH%\
```

however, the last COPY command is not correct.
The output says "The system cannot find the path specified."

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find these can be a PITA to debug when I have them.
Have you tried

```
echo %SeaProjectCrystalPATH%
DIR %SeaProjectCrystalPATH%\*.rpt
```

Those will help identify if the SOURCE of the copy is there
and
DIR %SeaMainMenuCrystalPATH%

This will help identify if the DESTINATION of the copy is there.